# cell format excel number to text

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, format

I have a file with 4 columns and over 7000 rows. The columns are formatted as `Number` **or** `Geral`.

But I'm using a plugging for php (`SimpleXLSX`) to read the xlsx file and create queries to insert into a database.

My problem is that when I have numbers like `810001001101114` in the number column and my php file read it, the output is: `81000100110111E+14`.

When I format the column to **`Text`** the value becomes `8,10001E+14` (it reads `81000100110111E+14` by my php). After I edit the cell (<kbd>F2</kbd>), it comes back to `810001001101114` **text**.

But I can't edit every single cell by hand. Is there a way to edit all cells by their same value **or** convert number cell to text cell without changing the output?

Comment: I need them as string. not int

Comment: Have you tried formatting the cells with a Special Format? Something like `000000000000000`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, somehow I got this...

I created another column and typed `=TEXT(A1;"0")` in the first cell of the new column. Replicate to all rows of that column this formula. Selected the column, Selected the `Copy Values` option and `pasted` the data in the original column.

After that, I just deleted the column that I created.

PS: The new column must be Text value to avoid any issues.